# Installation of driver failed

Tags: wireless, internet-connection

It says " please have a look at the log file for details: /var/log/jockey.log" and I have no idea where to find this so called file.

Answer (score 1):

It's in /var/log. Open a terminal (press ctrl-alt-t) and type

```
gedit /var/log/jockey.log
```

If you need help figuring out the contents / problem, I suggest you paste the file's contents in a pastebin (http://pastebin.ubuntu.com) and update your question with a link to it, so we can go have a look.